# Singleton class Background Services

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, singleton, background-task

I have a solution with 3 projects,

1. MainProject (UWP Application)
2. Common (Class Library)
3. Background Services (Windows Run-time Application)

MainProject references both Common and Background Services, and Background Services references Common.

I also have a singleton class stored in Common. The singleton class works correctly when referenced from the MainProject, however when i try to reference the singleton class from the background services project, all properties within the singleton class are null.

I have tried inspecting the GetInstance property of the singleton class. A new instance is not created when the singleton class is referenced from Background services, however the properties are still null.

The singleton class:

```
public class UserTokenInfo
{
    private static UserTokenInfo instance = null;
    private static object lockThis = new object();

    private UserTokenInfo() { }

    public static UserTokenInfo GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockThis)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new UserTokenInfo();

                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string expiry { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool isTokenValid()
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(expiry) > DateTime.Now)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Topic { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Website { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have created two instance for a common module in your application.

Try to exclude the static binding of library from one of the project and try then.

Use DLL/reference instead of static lib. Hope it will help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, could you please explain how I would do this in VS2015